# Copying cell value(s) based on values in adjecent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a beautiful Excel file which automatically imports values from CSV files into my worksheet, the data is pasted in the first empty row of my sheet.

The thing is that data can come from 3 different sources, say the column G is filled with either a 1, a 2 or a 3.

Based on the value in said column i'd like to paste the other values of that row to the first empty cell in a specific range in a different sheet. The sheet name is dependent on the Value in Column C, for which I created the following code:

```
Sub Lastcell()
Dim LR As String
Dim SheetName As String
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
SheetName = Range("C" & LR).Value
If SheetExists(SheetName) Then
    Else
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = SheetName
    End If
End Sub

Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional Wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    If Wb Is Nothing Then Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = (LCase(Wb.Sheets(SheetName).name) = LCase(SheetName))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

So I know which worksheet I’m copying to, now I want to select which row it goes to.

Say, if the value in the last cell of column G is 1, I want to copy the whole row to the first empty cell in row C, starting from C5.

if the value in the last cell of column G is 2, I want to copy the whole row to the first empty cell in row H, starting from H5.

if the value in the last cell of column G is 3, I want to copy the whole row to the first empty cell in row M, starting from M5.

My question is: How can i select a different paste range based on the value of a cell. Cell value is 1, paste to last empty cell in column A Cell value is 2, Paste to last empty cell in column B Cell value is 3, Paste to last empty cell in column C?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i select a different paste range based on the value of a cell.

Cell value is 1, paste to last empty cell in column A
Cell value is 2, Paste to last empty cell in column B
Cell value is 3, Paste to last empty cell in column C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long, NR as long
    Dim DestCol As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.ActiveSheet
    LR = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets(wsData.Cells(LR, "C").Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
        Select Case wsData.Cells(LR, "G").Value
            Case 1: DestCol = "C"
            Case 2: DestCol = "H"
            Case 3: DestCol = "M"
        End Select

        'Destination sheet and columns are now defined
        'Copy over what you want to the destination
        NR = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, DestCol).End(xlUp).Row
        If NR < 5 Then NR = 5
        wsDest.Cells(NR, DestCol).Resize(, 6).Value = wsData.Cells(LR, "A").Resize(, 6).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So it's working pretty much perfectly now, thanks for that!

I'd like to copy columns A-F if possible. Furthermore, how can i start copying to row 5 or 6 in the destination sheet?

Can't figure out how to put the Range in ws.Dest in this.




`wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, DestCol).End(xlUp).offset(1).Value = wsData.Range("A" & LR, "F" & LR).Value`

Comment: Works like a charm! I've just added .offset(1) to the last line to use next empty cell instead of overwriting the 5th cell constantly.
`wsDest.Cells(NR, DestCol).Resize(, 6).offset(1).Value = wsData.Cells(LR, "A").Resize(, 6).Value`

Thank you!